# prevent hyperlink control from reordering navigateurl attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-controls, navigateurl

I created a hyperlink control extended from HyperLink, but I do not know how to override the navigateurl property, the problem is: im using a jquery library that depends on the url to look like this

```
#TB_inline?height=285&amp;width=510&amp;inlineId=contactUsContent
```

problem with .net is that it reorders this into:

```
../controls/?height=285&width=510&inlineId=contactUsContent#TB_inline
```

how can i force it to accept my string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i was too hasty to ask this question, the simple solution was to decieve the hyperlink into making it an absolute url instead of relative, so all i had to do is insert a "/" at the beginning of the url

silly me!